# Finding third point of right triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image: Triangle image]

I have the length of BC,and AC and the coordinates of points A and C. I'm trying to find the coordinates of B.

Comment: Welcome to Math@StackExchange! What have you tried to solve this exercise?

Comment: Hint: If $A=(x_A,y_A)$ and $C=(x_C,y_C)$ then $B$ will be $(x_A+t(y_C-y_A),y_A-t(x_C-x_A))$ for suitable $t$

Comment: Before one gives suggestions, are you sure about the position of $A,B,C$ in your triangle? I would normally assume the right angle to be at $C$ and would also assign $A,B,C$ counter-clockwise.

Comment: I don't understand what is t and how do I take the BC length into account? The B point can be anywhere but the BC length makes it specific.

Comment: There is one datum too much because by Pythagoras $AB^2=AC^2+CB^2$.

Comment: Please don't change the question silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the sine and/or cosine of the angles that points A and/or C have with respect to the axes. Then find the same for the acute angles within the triangle. Geometry will then tell you the angles that BC has with respect to the axes and you can find the coordinates by multiplying the length of BC by these respective values and adding any offset from C if C is not on the origin.

Comment: Note that my answer does not assume that point C is at the origin. It is suggested in the drawing but not so stated in the question.

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter if one assumes $C$ to be at the origin or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Convert the coordinates of $A$ to polar with the pole at $C$. Then replace the modulus ($\rho=AC$) by $BC$ and add/subtract $\dfrac\pi2$ to the argument $\theta$. Convert back to Cartesian.

Comment: We do not know that point C is at the origin.

Comment: @poetasis: it is trivial to move the pole there.

Comment: Stupid downvote.

Comment: +1 for knowing something trivial that apparently is not widely known anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find the length of $AB$ (Pythagoras!). If you let the coordinates of $B$ be $(x,y),$ then since you know the other distances and coordinates, you can use the distance formula to find two equations in $x$ and $y$ (apply it to $|BA|$ and $|BC|$ in turn) that you can hopefully solve for $(x,y).$